# Algorithm for generating unique number across system

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have problem with me where I have to generate unique number throughout the system.Say an application 'X' generates value 'A' by using some inputs and this value 'A' will be used by some other application as input to generate some other value 'B'.

'A' and 'B' both values will be saved later in KDB. Purpose of doing this is to identify which value of 'A' triggered generation value of 'B'. 'A' are getting generated at very high speed so I am looking for algorithm which is fast and doesn't hamper the performance of application 'X'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a UUID. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier. They are generally based on things like MAC addresses, timestamps, hashes, and randomness. Their theoretical intent is to be globally unique. Depending on the platform there are often built in functions for generating them. I can expand on this more when I'm not on my phone if necessary, but start there.

You have likely run into them from time to time, https://www.uuidgenerator.net can give you some examples.

That said if you're inserting them in a database another strategy to investigate is using the databases auto assigned primary key ID numbers. Not always possible since you have to store them first to get an ID assigned, but philosophically sounds correct for your application.

You could also roll your own although there are many caveats. E.g. The time stamp of application startup concatenated with some internal counter. Just be aware of collision risks, even unlikely, e.g. two applications starting at the same time, or an incorrect system clock. I wouldn't consider this approach for serious usage given the presence of other more reliable strategies.

No matter what you use, I do recommend ultimately also using it as the primary key in your database. It will simplify things for you overall, and also having two unique ids in a database (e.g. UUID plus auto-generated primary key) denormalizes your database a bit (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).